# android- how to check local Sqlite database for new data and push notification continuously?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, contentobserver

I have an app for creating and reminding routine tasks that uses sqlite database locally.

I want when a task reaches its time remind the user with a push notification.
I worked on a service to check the database if the data & time of the task matches the data & time of the device shows a push notification.

first I decided to uses **Job scheduler**. but the minimum time for checking the database is 15 minutes.

then I tried **Alarm manager** for checking the database every one minute. but it seemed a bad idea because of the load of work.

then I read about **Content Observer** and found out it doesn't tell the exact new data which doesn't work for me.

what should I do? Is there another way or should I stick with Alarm Manager?

Comment: Alarm Manager is not suggestible. It drains the battery, if you frequently execute tasks on it. You better write the proper logic something like GCD of all of the task times as your wakeup time for your AlarmManager. Just to reduce the load.

Comment: What exactly is GCD?

Comment: Greatest Common Divisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a repeating alarm on an interval that checks the database, could you set one exact alarm when the task is scheduled? It executes just when the task is due. And upon a reboot, when your app receives the boot complete intent, it iterates through the database setting all the required one-time alarms?

Comment: For that I should have a service to know when the data is added. What kind of service should I use?

Comment: If data is added through your app's ui, then you don't need to monitor it because your app will know when the data changes.